# The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted on win 7

Tags: postgresql

I'm on win7 x64 and can't get PostgreSQL 14 running.

I have made a clean install. Removed all app data from the past versions.

Looked up all the solutions in here, but no fix.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: same image as in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35BDktCbGns

Comment: I don't know how to do the stack trace with process explorer

Answer (score 2):

I hope you were able to solve this, but this answer might help if someone else is having issues with pgAdmin on Windows 7.

When you install Postgres v14 in recent times, a newer version of pgAdmin 4 is installed along with the postgres installation. The latest pgAdmin version that is supported in windows 7 is  pgAdmin v 4.30.

Step 1: Go to Control Panel and select Uninstall Postgresql >> select individual components and uninstall just the pgAdmin.

Step 2: Download and install the supported version of pgAdmin.

This has solved the pgAdmin issue on windows 7 for me.

Comment: Download from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.30/windows/

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue running pgadmin 4 that comes with postgresSQL 15 on windows 7.

Turns out that pgadmin 4 depends on python 3.10.3, which is not compatible with win 7.

Python 3.10.3 reported missing `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` when run on win 7, which can by fixed by downloading the missing dll file in the following github link:
https://github.com/nalexandru/api-ms-win-core-path-HACK